# How to clear Keyboard memory?

Tags: c#-3.0

Hi I am using GetAsyncKeyState function in a loop to break loop when clicking Pause. Then again i am starting execution of the same loop. This time before  i am hitting Pause key loop was breaked. I want to flush this key in memory .How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you, `pause` is still in keyboard buffer, so you want to remove it?

```
if(Console.In.Peek() != -1) Console.In.Read();
```